# PHP Variable Keeps Showing Blank on Second Page

Tags: php, redirect, http-post, forms

I have a PHP page that renders an HTML form that sends data to PHP Page2 via POST, does some MySQL Commands and depending on the result, it will set `$status` to some text so I can echo it on the initial submit page. No matter what I do, shows nothing at all. If I remove `$status='';` at the top, it gives undefined variable so it seems it does not ever see `$status` again other than at the beginning with blank value.

#### Index.php (Submit Page)

```
<form method="post" name="sn_upload" id="sn_upload" action="upload.php">
<?php include 'upload.php'; ?>
<div>
   <label for="model">Model: </label><select id="model" name="model" title="Model">
        <option value="Model A">Model A</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <label for="sn">Serial Number: </label><input type="text" id="sn" name="sn" placeholder="Serial Number" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{11,13}"/><br><span class="error"><p id="sn_error" style="color:red;"></p></span><br>
    <?php echo $status; ?> //this shows nothing at all
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />


</div>
</form>
```

#### upload.php (MySQL Page)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "database";
$status = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Create connection
    $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
    } 

    $mod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['model']);
    $sn_num = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['sn']);
    $check = $con->query("SELECT * FROM rma_product WHERE pro_sn = ('$sn_num') ");

    if ($check->num_rows == 0)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO rma_product (m_type,pro_sn) VALUES ('$mod','$sn_num')";
    if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $status = "Success";
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        $status = "Failed";
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
else if ($check->num_rows >= 1)
    {
        $status = "Exists";

        header('Location: index.php');
    }

$con->close();
}
return $status;
?>
```

Comment: Is "Page 2" that you posted above named upload.php? If so, you're posting your form to that page *and* including that page in "Page 1"?

Comment: You want to post to page2 and then show the variable generated from page2 on page1?

Comment: Also pretty sure your not supposed to wrap your variables in your SELECT statement with parenthesis, I've never seen that markup before.

Comment: Plus the HTML select tag shouldn't be self-closing (i.e. `<select id="model" name="model" title="Model" />` and then has corresponding close tag: `</select>`....)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yes, trying to get $status to be displayed on Page 1

Comment: @SamOnela I fixed the /> for select but seemed to be working fine before with it included. Good catch though.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, So Page 2 is upload.php and I have an include for upload.php on Page 1 which is index.php

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Well the SELECT with ('$sn_num') seems to work because it knows that if num_rows is 0 and after an insert I try same SN again and it knows that it is >= 1

Comment: Just because it seemingly works doesn't mean it's correct and/or will always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each case, whenever a non-empty string literal is assigned to `$status` (i.e. when attempting to insert a record or reporting that an associated record already exists), there is a call to `header()`. That will tell the browser to navigate to the other page, essentially ending the current page execution. Thus after that, the value stored in `$status` does not persist.

```
        $status = "Success";
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        $status = "Failed";
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
else if ($check->num_rows >= 1)
{
    $status = "Exists";
    header('Location: index.php');
```

So you either need to figure out how to set that value without redirecting or send the value along to the page redirected to. Options for that include appending the value to the query string (e.g. `header('Location: index.php?status='.$status);` and check for a value in `$_GET['status']` to assign to `$status` in index.php), using the session (as Nosajimiki mentioned), etc.

Comment: I have the redirect going back to submit page in the event another sn needs to be added

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense given the code in upload.php. I updated the explanation to try being more explicit.

Comment: Well this worked mostly, so the URL after redirect from post shows index.php?status=Exists which is good but still does not echo anything on the form page

Comment: Then have index.php check the query string: `$status = isset($_GET['status'])?$_GET['status']:'';`...

Comment: I was able to get this working with `if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "Exists") !== false){
echo "Found";
}`  Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use $status as a session variable.  If you want to keep a PHP variable between pages, create a session and save it as a session variable

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
...
$_SESSION["status"] = $status;
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

You can then call it on other subsequent pages using $_SESSION["status"]